# Live Keyframing

Tags: python, animation, keyframes, fcurves, csv

Does anybody know if there is a good way to "record keyframes live?". For example - I want to hit the space bar while the playhead is moving to time a parameter manually instead of tediously plotting the frames. I've seen there are some pretty crazy things like with with Mocap, but I'm really looking for something simple, like pressing the spacebar.

Also open to 3rd party software to create a CSV file or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

### Add Marker

Pressing <kbd>M</kbd> (with your mover over the timeline) will add a marker at the current frame.

Markers are just visual landmarks, but they can help you to, ie, synchronize some action with an event in the scene, or with a soundtrack.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/markers.html